# In group-theory, are the elements in a set other sets or are they precise numbers?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I am starting out with group theory for my computer science degree, it's part of the basic maths subject, it is covered in about 1.5 pages and then moves on with topology.

From what I understood you have a set, eg. $M=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and with this set you can define an "internal composition law" or "operation" with this set so that $(M,*)$ is an abelian group.

In my textbook I understood that an operation should return an element within the set $M$. So my question is,

> Are the elements of $M$ variables that can only have one value, or are these elements other sets (can be ranges of values)?

I think I am missing something here... Someone said that I can start with examples like $a^2=b^2=c$, however would $a^2$ still be part of the original set?

Because say $a = 86, b = 42, c = 0, d = 7$; then $a^2$ wouldn't be part of our M set from what I believe.

Maybe don't know what they are asking me to do exactly, I also thought of supposing the "operation" is a sum, so if I sum $a + b$ the answer wouldn't be part of set $M$ either.

I have studied set theory before, stuff like intersections, unions, complements, etc but I am completely new to group-theory.

And to all the unfriendly people out there, you don't have to answer or comment if you don't want to help, maybe work on your own personal issues before insulting someone who is just asking a question.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: It's a Spanish book, I can send you the pdf i you like, it's called fundamentos matemáticos de la informática by Sanz y Torres.

Comment: Just the name will do. I didn't ask for my benefit.

Comment: Perhaps a good example of a group not having numbers as elements is the general linear group $GL_n(K)$ from linear algebra. The elements are matrices with nonzero determinant. The basic examples of a group in elementary number theory are $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/n$. Also the symmetric group $S_n$ and the alternating group $A_n$ are good examples. You should look at more examples of groups. Then everything becomes more explicit and (hopefully) easier.

Comment: Do you mean "topology", not "topography"?

Comment: Thanks for the input, yes topology is probably the word, maybe I got the translation wrong.

Comment: It might help to see some more concrete examples of groups. For example, the set of all invertible $n \times n$ matrices with real number entries is a group (the operation is matrix multiplication). The set of all real $n \times n$ matrices with determinant $1$ is also a group (again, the operation is matrix multiplication). There are also finite matrix groups. The set of all permutations on $\{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$ is a group.

Comment: "Then $a^2$ wouldn't be part of the set". In this context, $a^2$ would be a shorthand for $a*a$ where $*$ is the operation of the group, not regular multiplication. So if $a = 86, b = 42, c = 0, d = 7$ and we define $86*86=42*42=0*0=7$ and $7*x=x*7=x$ for all $x$ in $M$ and $86*42=42*86=0$ and $86*0=0*86=42$ and $42*0=0*42=86$, that'd be a group with "$a=86$..." where $a^2=d$ even though the usual number product of $86$ with itself isn't $7$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're abstract elements, just symbols. For example, with $M$ as in the question, there must be an identity element, call it $e$, and there must be an element $x\neq e$ with $x^2=e$.

However, you can have numbers as elements of groups, such as $(\Bbb Z,+)$ and $(\Bbb R, +)$.

Comment: Thank you Shaun

Comment: You're welcome, @OLAVEIVINDGILJE. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).